# Change color on correct output

Tags: javascript, colors, output, p5.js, caesar-cipher

I would like the color of the 3 blinking red lights to change to green once I get a corrected encrypted or decrypted message (either when a user puts a number between 1 and 26 in the key filed and presses encrypt/decrypt or when he gets an output different from a sequence of "undefined"). Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?
Thanks

```
let inps = [];
let buttons = [];
let alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
let backImage;

function preload (){
  backImage = loadImage('images/back.jpg')
}

function setup() {
  
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
//  Type here your plain or encryted message
  inps.push(createElement('textarea'));
  inps[0].position(20, 70);
  inps[0].size(550, 150);
  inps[0].style('background', '#3C3C3B');
  inps[0].style('color', '#ffffff');
  
  
//   Key
  inps.push(createInput(' Insert number from 1 to 26'));
  inps[1].position(20, 290);
  inps[1].size(200, 20);
  inps[1].style('background', '#3C3C3B');
  inps[1].style('color', '#ffffff');
  
//  Encrypted / Decrypted message
  inps.push(createElement('textarea'));
  inps[2].position(20, 370);
  inps[2].size(550, 150);
  inps[2].style('background', '#3C3C3B');
  inps[2].style('color', '#ffffff');

  
  buttons.push(createButton('Encrypt'));
  buttons[0].position(370, 275);
  buttons[0].size(100, 50);
  buttons[0].mousePressed(encrypt);
  
  buttons.push(createButton('Decrypt'));
  buttons[1].position(475, 275);
  buttons[1].size(100, 50);
  buttons[1].mousePressed(decrypt);
  
  noStroke();

}

function draw() {
  background(backImage);
  fill(255)
  text('Type here your plain or encryted message', 20, 60);
  text('Encrypted / Decrypted message', 20, 360);
  text('Key', 20, 280);
  light()
  blinkRed()
  // blinkGreen()
}

function light(){
  for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++){
     noStroke();
     fill(255)
     ellipse(25*x+510, 30, 20);
}
}
function blinkRed(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    noStroke();
     if(frameCount % 60 < 30) {
    fill(50);
    } else {
    fill(255,0,0)
  } 
    ellipse(25*i+510, 30, 15);
  }
}
// function blinkGreen(){
//   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
//     noStroke();
//      if(frameCount % 60 < 30 && buttons[0].mousePressed) {
//     fill(50);
//     } else {
//     fill(0,255,0)
//   ellipse(25*i+510, 30, 15);
//   }
//   }
// }


function encrypt() {
  const initial = inps[0].value().toUpperCase();
  const shift = int(inps[1].value()) % 26;
  let output = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < initial.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.includes(initial[i])) {
      output += alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(initial[i]) + shift + 26) % 26];
    } else {
      output += initial[i];
    }
  }
  inps[2].value(output);
}

function decrypt() {
  const initial = inps[0].value().toUpperCase();
  const shift = int(inps[1].value());
  let output = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < initial.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.includes(initial[i])) {
      output += alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(initial[i]) - shift + 26) % 26];
    } else {
      output += initial[i];
    }
  }
  inps[2].value(output);
}
```

Comment: You should probably just use one function called `blinkColor()` to reduce repetition. At the top, have a global variable called something like `let cryptedYet = false;`, and in the encrypt and decrypt functions, set `cryptedYet = true;`. In the function `blinkColor()`, before you fill, test for both `cryptedYet === true` and `parseInt(inps[1].html()) >= 1 && parseInt(inps[1].html()) <= 26`. This is when the color should be green. When any of these conditions are false, then the color should be red. Also set the "on change" attribute of the text input to set `cryptedYet = false;`

Comment: Like this? Because if this is correct it is not working  `function blinkcolor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    noStroke();
    if (frameCount % 60 < 30) {
      fill(50);
    } else if (cryptedYet === true && parseInt(inps[1].html()) >= 1 && parseInt(inps[1].html()) <= 26) {
      fill(0, 255, 0)
    } else if (cryptedYet === false && parseInt(inps[1].html()) < 1 && parseInt(inps[1].html()) > 26) {
      fill(255, 0, 0)
    }
    ellipse(25 * i + 510, 30, 15);
  }
}`

Comment: currently you have an if --- else if --- else if, and it will work it you just have if --- else if --- else. you have something wrong with your last else if (those all need to be || not &&) but you can just use an else to make it work. Also don't post code in the comments like that because the formatting doesn't make it look good.